# I can't add/remove service reference after migration to VS2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, service-reference

I get this error after I try to Update/Delete/Create a service reference:

The configuration for the service reference could not be added due to the following issue: Attribute 'binding' is required on element 'endpoint'.

In VS2010 it was working fine.

I've tried a lot of things included:

**Strike one:**
Unchecked the "Reuse Types in referenced assemblies" checkbox in the Configure Service reference dialog.

**Strike two:**
Remove all the references from the project, add them again
Unchecked the non-Microsoft dlls in the Configure Service reference dialog.

**Strike three:**
-Uninstalled/Reinstalled VS2012

-Deleted/Remapped original project

-Added the service reference in a brand new project

-Delete old service .wsdl's, .xsd's, .disco's, .svcinfo, .svcmap from the original project

-Edited the .csproj xml to remove the old files and insert the new files

-Copied the service files from the new project to the original project

-Now the old project builds but I still can't add/remove/update any service references

P.S. I really loved VS2010 but I can't say the same about VS2012... still...

Answer (score 0):

1.Just open your VS-2012 solution in VS -2010

1. Clean the client project
2. Add service like as you add your service previous => Configure service=>Update Service
3. Close the solution from vs-2010
4. Now Open your solution in VS-2012

Your Project is ready for VS-2012

You can also see the link

[Add Service After Migrate VS-2012](http://atikpassion.blogspot.com/2013/01/add-service-after-migrating-silverlight.html)

Comment: how should it open in vs2010? it not possible

Comment: please See the Link: "Add Service After Migrate VS-2012"